# SipML5 with Kamailio as Sip Server return 488 in make Call

Tags: kamailio, sipml5

I have setup Kamailio with websocket module. When I register with sipML5 its going well. But returns **488 Not Acceptable Here** when I trying to call.

488 means: Some aspect of the session description or the Request-URI is not acceptable, or Codec issue. I try check response SIP when called Method INVITE it has PCMU/8000 & PCMA/8000.

I think it's not a Codec issue *CMIIW. Is it possible I have the wrong config for sipML5?

I'm using RTPProxy and coTurn for TURN Server

Answer (score 0):

Make sure IP addresses located in SDP is correct and also you should give a permission for IP addresses.